# Is $n\log_{2}\log_{2}n = O(n\log_{3}\log_{3}n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I've proven that $n\log_{2}\log_{2}n = \Omega (n\log_{3}\log_{3}n)$ but is $n\log_{2}\log_{2}n = O(n\log_{3}\log_{3}n)$ also true? Looks like it's not and actually $n\log_{2}\log_{2}n = \omega(n\log_{3}\log_{3}n)$. A problem of CLRS led me ask this.

Comment: We have "$\log_{a}b$" or "$\log_{a}(b)$"  for $\log$ function with base "$a$" and argument "$b$", but what is $$\log_{a}^{b}$$
Is this power of $\log$? if yes, then what is argument? fix, please.

Comment: @zkutch It is just a logarithm with base 2 and argument $\log(n)$ and the other one is a logarithm as well. I'll fix it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37379/890149 does this answer your question?

Comment: @nirshahar Yes. My question got solved. The idea of changing the base of the logarithm and computing the limit had stricken my mind but I was lazy to compute the limit! I computed it and it got solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, also we can get a tighter result that show us $ n\log_2\log_2n=\Theta(n\log_3\log_3n)$ .Suppose $c',c''>0$ is a constant, hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log\log n}{n\log_{3}\log_{3}n} = \frac{n\log\log n}{cn\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log n}{\log 3}\right)}{\log 3}}=c'$$
Also
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log_{3}\log_{3}n}{n\log\log n} = \frac{cn\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log n}{\log 3}\right)}{\log 3}}{n\log\log n}=c''.$$

**Note that constant factor have no effect on the growth rate of asymptotic functions, therefore**

$$n\log_2\log_2n=\Theta(n\log_3\log_3n).$$

Comment: I also solved it using the limit but I did some more calculations to show that indeed the limit exists: Things like the L'Hopital's rule.